# How to set max-width for DIV contents but not the DIV itself?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

**UPDATE**: Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/720v4zdy/8/

I'm customizing a tumblr blog to match someone's site and it's almost in good shape. We started with a theme that already matched it closely and then made some changes in CSS.

The last problem I can't solve is how to make the navigation bar stretch the entire page while containing all of the links in a max-width of 1024px.

Here's the tumblr blog WIP: http://craftysheepblog.tumblr.com/

I want the navigation bar to stretch the entire page, but the links to be contained with a max-width of 1024px. The trouble here is I only have one DIV to do this with, so I'm not quite sure how to make it happen.

I'm using this currently, which works somewhat. It gets ugly when you make the browser window smaller though.

```
#top nav {
    background-color: rgb(45, 50, 51);
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 11px 22%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You should put the exact code in question in a fiddle and post that - it makes it easier to isolate the problem and solution.

Comment: Thanks! I did that now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `nav` to `max width: 1024px` and fill the "gaps" on the sides with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. You'll need to hide the `overflow` on `header#top` to avoid sideways scrolling, because the pseudo elements are set wider than the content.

This does rely on you setting the height of your nav and following suit with the `<a>` (`height`, `line-height`, etc.) ...

Also - tweak some more; there is a 600px break point in your CSS on the live site that will interfere with this (along with a lot of your extra CSS that I didn't clean up).

```css
body {
  color: rgb(38, 39, 43);
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  margin: 0;
}
#top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#top .title {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-top: 18px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top nav {
  background-color: rgb(45, 50, 51);
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 50px auto 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#top nav::before{
  background: rgb(45,50,51);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  right: 100%;
}
#top nav::after{
  background: rgb(45,50,51);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#top nav a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

#top nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#top nav a:hover {
  color: #52A708;
}

#top .headimg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">
      <a href="/" class="active">
        <div class="title">Page Title</div>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <a class="page" href="#">Link 1</a><a class="page" href="#">Link 2</a><a class="page" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. I've never thought about using ::before/::after elements like that. It even let me keep all the text left justified. There's a lot of ways I can think this sort of trick would benefit other sites I've done too. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `max-width: 1024px;`

Comment: This would fix the content width issue, but then the black navigation bar background would not extend across the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a ul inside of a div as your navigation bar. The ul can contain all of your links. That way, the div can have a width that spans the entire page while the unordered list has a max width of 1024px.

Example code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #nav {
                width: 100%;
                height: 20%;
            }
            #nav-links {
                max-width: 1024px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="nav-links">
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can style your ul as a nav bar however you like. Here's a good link for that: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: I agree this would be ideal. Since I'm trying to make this as simple as possible for the person I'm helping, I want them to be able to just copy and paste the CSS into their tumblr. Adding <ul> elements to their base theme would be tough for most people I think.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information you have shared it is hard to say. Obviously the cleanest way to accomplish this is to insert another element (div or otherwise) around these child elements, and assign *it* a max-width... however this does not sound as if it is an option for you?

If you know how many elements you want to make up the 1024px, you could assign their widths manually (i.e. give each of the four children a width of 256px, or something similar).

If you do not know any of these things, and your options for the space are limited, Javascript is your best option. You could write a script that counts the children, and either assigns their widths appropriately or inserts clears at the proper location.

If you expand your question to target a specific approach, I'm sure myself and the many gurus on here will be able to give you more specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

The links should stretch as normal but start to shrink when they each exceed 341px which is 1023px as a total width.

*Note: Snippet best viewed in Full Page mode.*

**Relevant CSS**

```
 #top nav {
      background-color: rgb(45, 50, 51);
      color: white;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 11px 22%;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: baseline;

    #top nav a {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin: 0px 15px;
      flex: 0 1 341px;
    }
```

```css
body {
  color: rgb(38, 39, 43);
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.row {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#top {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#top .title {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-top: 18px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#top nav {
  background-color: rgb(45, 50, 51);
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 11px 22%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: baseline;
}
#top nav a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  flex: 0 1 341px;
}
#top nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#top nav a:hover {
  color: #52A708;
}
#top .headimg {
  display: none;
}
#posts {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.column,
.columns {
  padding: 0;
}
#posts article:nth-child(1) {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#posts article .title {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif", Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: rgb(38, 39, 43);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#posts article footer {
  display: none;
}
#paginate {
  display: none;
}
#bottom {
  border: none;
}
#bottom {
  border: none;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 small-centered columns">

      <img class="headimg" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/x.gif?v=1">


      <a href="/" class="active">
        <div class="title">Page Title</div>
      </a>


      <div class="description"></div>

      <nav>


        <a class="page" href="/online-store">Shop NAO</a><a class="page" href="/nao-couture">NAO Couture</a><a class="page" href="/nao-experience">NAO Experience</a>







      </nav>
    </div>
    <!--.columns-->
  </div>
  <!--.row-->
</header>
```